# I am looking for sum of the sales made since June-1997 on a yearly basis according to the category_name

Tags: sql, postgresql

but i have some problem in sum Is there any other solution?

```sql
select EXTRACT( YEAR FROM shipped_date) As shippedyear,
       category_name,
       sum(unit_price*quantity*(1-discount))::Numeric(16,2) as categorysales    
FROM data1.order_details 
natural join data2.orders 
natural join data3.categories
where shipped_date >='1997-07-01'
GROUP BY shipped_date,category_name,unit_price,quantity,discount
order by categorysales desc
```

Comment: where are you running this query? sql server, postegre, mysql or what else?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Multiple joins may produce incorrect output. Aggregate by single table (or minimal tables set) in the subquery then join another tables. In multiple-table query always specify table alias for each column name.

Comment: Don't GROUP BY columns that you also include in an aggregate function

Comment: You must use `GROUP BY shippedyear, category_name` only.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.